# sap.m.Timepicker - minutesStep property not working

Tags: sapui5

How do I configure the sap.m.Timepicker to display minutes in 15 minute intervals?

```
<TimePicker
    displayFormat="HH:mm"
    minutesStep="15"
>

</TimePicker>
```

The above code is ignored, I can select any time.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this, but you need version 1.40 at least - below it's not working

```
oDTPicker = new sap.m.TimePicker({
    displayFormat : "HH:mm",
    minutesStep : 5
});
```

In XML view definition I got an error like minutesStep="5" is not typeof Integer...